# paging with Razor syntax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC with EF6. How to add paging with items from model in view without calling any function from controller?

```html
@model IEnumerable<myApp.Models.myTable>
<tbody>
@foreach(var item in Model){
  <tr>
    <!--here I want to add paging with items from model-->
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.name)</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Comment: this would have nothing to do with EF6.  If you want to keep processing away from the controller than it all has to be done on the client.  Steve Harris has a good option below if you are using JQuery, but there are others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a new MVC project will typically include jQuery by default, you can use jQuery Datatables. You'll need to add some script to your page and ensure you can refer to your table (by adding an id):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#yourTableId').datatable();
    };
</script>
```

This is the bare minimum. You can find information on jQuery datatables very easily online for some more in-depth information.

If you are returning thousands of records, you might want to consider going back through the controller for paging instead to avoid using up too much memory on the client.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ offers to extensions you can use to implement paging: `Skip` and `Take`

```
@model IEnumerable<myApp.Models.myTable>

@{
    int pageSize = 20;
    int pageIndex = ViewBag.PageIndex as int? ?? 0;
}

<tbody>
@foreach(var item in Model.Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.name)</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

BUT I think this should be done in the controller and not in the View, because the data should already be queried from the DB there and thus you would need to query ALL data on every page.

Comment: Yes.  The controller would need to know the value of PageIndex which would have been sent from the client in subsequent requests.